# Twitter Search API- How to implement premium access keys in NODE.JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am using npm-twit in node.js to get tweets with the twitter search api.

I am totally new to programming but need it for my master thesis. I therefore got the premium account with full archive access to the search requests.

With the standard free api access my code worked without any problems. But now I do not know how to correctly implement access tokens etc.

I tried putting `product` and `label` in different places and changed `q` to `query` and `data.statues` to `data.results` but anything I tried gives me several error codes - like

```
'code: 195, message: 'Missing or invalid url parameter.' 
'code: 25, message: 'Query parameters are missing.'
'message: 'Sorry, that page does not exist', code: 34'.
```

Or tells me that tweets.length does not exist (even though it worked before).

Or a simple 'null' 
(when I use this code snipped :

```
    T.get('search/tweets/fullarchive/:dev', params , gotData);   function gotData(err, data, response){console.log(data)}

)
```

//This is the current code which is not working

```
var Twit = require('twit'); 
var config = require('./config');

var T = new Twit({
  consumer_key:         'XXX',
  consumer_secret:      'XXX',
  access_token:         'XXX',
  access_token_secret:  'XXX',
  timeout_ms:           60*1000,
  strictSSL:            true,
  app_only_auth: true,

PRODUCT: 'fullarchive',
LABEL: 'dev',});

var params = { 
query: 'VW',
fromDate:'201801010000',
toDate:'201901010000',
followers_count:1000,
maxResults: 500,
result_type: 'popular',
lang: 'en' 
//next: ''
 }

T.get('search/tweets/fullarchive/:dev', params , gotData);
//T.get('search/tweets', params , gotData); - gives me all results in standard api


function gotData(err, data, response)
{
var tweets = data.results; //var tweets = data.statuses - gives me what I need in standard api
for (var i = 0; i < tweets.length; i++)

console.log(tweets[i].text, tweets[i].retweet_count,tweets[i].created_at,tweets[i].id_str,tweets[i].favorite_count,);
```

With this code I get an error `'Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of null'`

Ideally I want to get information about the tweet containing its text, creation date, retweet count, tweet id, favorite count - and if possible the "next" token when needed.

I would really appreciate any help!